# Calculate Entry exit times in attendence system

Tags: sql, talend

I am trying to format the Entry and Exit times in an attendance system. I have been able to format the data to the below form.

```
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+
| Emp_Name | IO_Date_Only | IO_Status |     IO_Time      | Flag |
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+
| AA       | 08-01-2018   | Enter     | 08-01-2018 11:44 | N    |
| AA       | 08-01-2018   | Exit      | 08-01-2018 11:51 | N    |
| AA       | 08-01-2018   | Exit      | 08-01-2018 11:52 | Y    |
| AA       | 08-02-2018   | Exit      | 08-02-2018 11:44 | N    |
| AA       | 08-02-2018   | Exit      | 08-02-2018 11:51 | Y    |
| AA       | 08-02-2018   | Exit      | 08-02-2018 11:52 | Y    |
| BB       | 08-01-2018   | Exit      | 08-01-2018 11:44 | N    |
| BB       | 08-01-2018   | Exit      | 08-01-2018 11:51 | Y    |
| BB       | 08-01-2018   | Enter     | 08-01-2018 11:52 | N    |
| BB       | 08-02-2018   | Enter     | 08-02-2018 11:44 | N    |
| BB       | 08-02-2018   | Enter     | 08-02-2018 11:51 | Y    |
| BB       | 08-02-2018   | Exit      | 08-02-2018 11:52 | N    |
| BB       | 08-02-2018   | Enter     | 08-02-2018 11:55 | N    |
| BB       | 08-02-2018   | Exit      | 08-02-2018 11:57 | N    |
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+
```

I the above data if I take  the 1st and 2nd row you see that 1st is and entry and the 2nd is an exit. However the 3rd row is also an exit. When finally trying to pull this data I would like to ignore the second row but take the 3rd row.

Basically what I want to do is if there are two consecutive Entry then I need to pull the 1st row and if there are consecutive Exits then I need to pull the last Exit row for that Group I have formatted the source to the above output using Talend  but now I am kind of stuck.

The output should look like below

```
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+
| Emp_Name | IO_Date_Only | IO_Status |     IO_Time      | Flag |
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+
| AA       | 08-01-2018   | Enter     | 08-01-2018 11:44 | N    |
| AA       | 08-01-2018   | Exit      | 08-01-2018 11:52 | Y    |
| BB       | 08-01-2018   | Enter     | 08-01-2018 11:52 | N    |
| BB       | 08-02-2018   | Enter     | 08-02-2018 11:44 | N    |
| BB       | 08-02-2018   | Exit      | 08-02-2018 11:52 | N    |
| BB       | 08-02-2018   | Enter     | 08-02-2018 11:55 | N    |
| BB       | 08-02-2018   | Exit      | 08-02-2018 11:57 | N    |
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+
```

Comment: shoot again the data did not get formatted to the correct format. Can someone direct me to a manual how to post questions or rather how to format the data for posting. I used this as a reference but it seems it did not  work https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Select the text and press `control-k` or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: What is the flag for? Becuase you said select the last one, but you have 5 exit in a row for same employee. Will help a lot if you add more logic details and show us your desire output

Comment: The five Exits that you have mentioned has two different dates. Basically I am creating groups on Name, Date_Only and IO_Status. If more than one consecutive entries then the first is marked as N and the remaining as Y. Y means it is a repetition. So an Employee has made two consecutive exits without an entry

Comment: Also I need to add a condition that if the first record for a day is Exit then I need to ignore that record and if the last record for the day is Entry then also I need to ignore that record

Comment: Hello, you said "if the last record for the day is Entry then also I need to ignore that record", but in your output you have an "Enter" record for BB on "08-01-2018", even though it is the last record for that employee for that day ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select emp_name, IO_Status, IO_Date_Only, min(IO_Time) as IN, max(IO_Time) as OUT
from table
group by emp_name, IO_Status, IO_Date_Only;
```

Comment: Would this not result in getting only two records for a date which is not what I want. I would like to get all the records for a day for a particular employee without a consecutive repetition of two Exits or two entries.

Comment: Hello, can you provide a sample OUTPUT that you want from the table that you have given?

Comment: Provided the sample output in the question

Comment: Any suggestions any one ??